# A que se debe el error (non-fast-forward) failed to push some refs

Tags: git, github

> To https://github.com/JuanDAlzate/Ludovico.git  ! [rejected]
>   gh-pages -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some
>   refs to 'https://github.com/JuanDAlzate/Ludovico.git' hint: Updates
>   were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint:
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git
>   pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
>   fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Estoy tratando de subir la rama gh-pages y me indica esto, ya intenté bajando los cambios del repositorio remoto y aún no he podido solucionarlo, el problema es cuando se me presenta esta interfaz que no se como se agrega el commit y como logro salir de aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es lo que se presenta en estos momentos es una imagen de muestra, lo que pude hacer fue borrar esta rama desde el repositorio remoto, pero quisiera saber como logro salir de esta interfaz

Comment: Puedes copiar los comandos que has intentado?

Comment: ¿No tendrás commits pendientes en esa rama?

Comment: Pueden ver la modificacion de la pregunta para mas informacion gracias por su colaboracion

Comment: Verifica con `git status` para ver si hay una divergencia de archivos y actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu rama esta atrasada frente a la rama remota, para solucionarlo primero debes hacer un pull para actualizar tu rama local al ultimo commit de la rama remota.

```
git pull
```

Cuando aparece la interface (de la imagen) cargas el mensaje del commit (puedes dejar el que viene por defecto) y luego pulsas la secuencia <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> (que significa Grabar y salir en el editor `vi` el que aparece en la imagen)

Esto concluirá el pull **si no hay conflictos.**

Finalmente puedes hacer el:

```
git push origin gh-pages
```

Comment: [No](https://adamcod.es/2014/12/10/git-pull-correct-workflow.html) [uséis](https://coderwall.com/p/jgn6-q/git-pull-is-evil) [git](https://coderwall.com/p/7aymfa/please-oh-please-use-git-pull-rebase) [pull](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/). Mejor `git fetch && git merge` o `git fetch && git rebase`.

Comment: No concuerdo, el mensaje de Merge que se produce vía pulo es importante para saber cuando dos ramas se unieron.

Comment: En mi comentario anterior hay enlazados cuatro artículos que explican que `git pull` puede producir resultados inesperados y que hay alternativas.

Comment: Te refieres al único link?

Comment: Gracias por su colaboracion bendiciones

Comment: No, me refiero a los cuatro links.

Comment: @astrojuanlu lol.. sutil

Answer (score 3):

En mi caso había aplicado algunos cambios que no le gustaba al git por lo que tuve que reversar los mismos a través del siguiente comando:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Donde el 1 indica la cantidad de commits que estaba por delante de la rama. Luego de reversar y perder lo que había hecho (consejo hace backup) pude descargarme los cambios de la rama con el comando:

```
git pull
```