# Problema con login de Github en eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, github, login

Quiero compartir un proyecto de `JavaFx` creado en `Eclipse Neon .1a Release (4.6.1)` en [GitHub](https://github.com/). Estoy utilizando las herramientas nativas del IDE, ya hice el repositorio local, solo me falta crear el `remote`.

Utilizando la pestaña `Git Repositories`, hice clic derecho en `remotes` -> `create new remote`, `new URI` lo tengo configurado de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en precionar `Saven and Push` me sale una ventana nueva con el titulo de `Login`, pidiendome de nuevo mis credenciales de [GitHub](https://github.com/), `User` y `Password`, las vuelvo a introducir y sale esta ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el repositorio de [GitHub](https://github.com/) no parece que hubo ningun cambio ni nada.

Soy algo nuevo utilizando `Eclipse` para compartir proyectos pero se me hace muy raro todo esto, es como si estuviera introduciendo mal mis credenciales, ya cambie la contraseña de mi [GitHub](https://github.com/) y aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: has intentado cambiar el protocolo Https por SSH?

Comment: Lo he resuelto! he utilizado las siguientes respuestas para solucionarlo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614370/problems-with-pushing-to-github-repository-from-eclipse-auth-fail y http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474186/egit-rejected-non-fast-forward

Comment: Gracias @ArieCwHat

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [A que se debe el error (non-fast-forward) failed to push some refs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8516/a-que-se-debe-el-error-non-fast-forward-failed-to-push-some-refs)

Answer (score 0):

inicia tu cuenta desde el git con interfaz

para hacerlo debes ir a la `rueda options` y desde ahi te

logueas

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que no es de autenticación, el error es similar al mostrado en la consola cuando se usa el bash

> [rejected]  master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Es algo común cuando iniciamos con GIT, primero debemos asegurar realizar `Git Pull` ya que en ocasiones tenemos pendiente bajar la versión del master.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posteriormente puedes realizar `Git Push`, lo cual se realizaría sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]